# Getting progress via Server Sent Events. Which setup to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events

I have this setup:

[image: Architecture]

Could someone point me in the right direction on a setup to get the progress sent from the fetch server up to the web browsers and API clients, e.g. via SSE (Server Sent Events)?

I'm looking for a solution where the fetch server can process fetches from multiple end users and report progress back simultaneously as the fetches can take 5-15 seconds.

I'm using Ruby on Rails for the servers, but other solutions are welcomed, as long as they're Ruby as much of the business logic is built in Ruby.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might take a look at [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) (see RailsCasts [#260](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) and [#316](http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub))

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Couldn't I just use server sent events?

Comment: Sure; the specific delivery mechanism isn't super important as long as it supports the browsers you want to support, etc. I suppose then that your question has more to do with communication between the fetch server and the API server?

Comment: Yeah exactly. The problem (?) is how to serve requests simultaneously from the fetch server up to the clients as the requests can take 5-10 seconds to complete. ? I haven't got much experience with this.

Comment: > "...as long as it supports the browsers you want to support" should read, "as long as it's supported by all the browsers _and proxy servers/firewalls/gateways_ your users are using"